# Is there a way to make Maven Depend on a SNAPSHOT only if a release isn't available?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

Given that we have a project called tools-lib.jar and it currently is at version 1.0.0 and other projects such as rest-api.war have a dependency on tools-lib-1.0.0.jar. Lets assume that both tools-lib and our rest api are under development by separate teams with separate timelines. What I would like to do is make my rest-api.war depend on tools-lib-2.0.0.jar. If the 2.0.0 release version isn't there, the application would go build against 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Does anyone know of a way to configure this via maven?

The goal of this is that if the rest-api is done before the tools lib, we don't have to go back through and change all the dependencies manually in order to build against the release, it will just do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` if the release is available you have to change that.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. Id rather not go through all the dependent projects and change them.